# How to use call function of javascript with object as one of the arguments?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to use Javascript's classic `.call` method. I have a function definition which accepts object as parameter.

When I try to invoke this function using .call(), I need to provide the context 'this' and the object param. I am not able to do so. Can someone help ?

Here is the code:

```
//options is the object param
 var setupSomething = function(options) {
    //function definition goes here
}
```

This function is a member function of class `MyView`.

I have another class `GuestView` from which I need to invoke this function by 
providing GuestView's context(`this`).

Here is the code:

```
MyView.prototype.setupSomething.call(this, options);
```

The problem is when the parser hits the definition of `setupSomething`, the context `this` which should belong to `GuestView` is not the one. Instead, it is the context of `MyView`. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

More code:

```
//This is instantiation of GuestView
var guestView = new GuestView({model: model});
guestView.render();

 //This is declaration of GuestView where guestView.render() hits after            invocation  
var GuestView = Backbone.View.extend( {
    initialize: function() {
        //setting of default variables, methods etc goes here
    },

    render: function() {
        var options = {key1: value1, key2: value2}
        this.someMemberFunc1();
        this.someMemberFunc2();
        MyView.prototype.setupSomething(this, options);//MyView is declared and defined in some other file, that's why it's prototype is used here. 
    }
})    
`
```

Comment: Is `this` definitely what you expect it to be on the line where you invoke `setupSomething.call(...`?

Comment: Do you have access to the instance of GuestView from that code snippet?

Comment: @PhilVarg , @James Thorpe: Yes, instance of `GuestView` calls one of the member functions inside where setupSomething is invoked and hence `this` refers to context of GuestView

Comment: @PhilVarg: The documentation of call in MDN says that call accepts this and individual arguments. Is it because of that passing object param is not acceptable ?

Comment: There really isn't enough code posted here to be able to help... can you post more code around calling the _.call_ function within guestView's context?

Comment: @Sidd: Added more code. I think it's enough to get the problem now.

Comment: That code says that `this` inside `render` will be your `GuestView` instance. How is `setupSomething` defined?

Comment: @muistooshort : setupsomething is defined as a member function of another view and that's the primary reason to use .`call()` to invoke setupsomething from instance of another view where it has to be used but not defined since it is already defined in other view and just reused here using prototype chain. You can refer code.

Comment: Then what's wrong with Sidd's answer? If using `call` as he does isn't working then there's something going on in your code that you're not showing us. BTW, what you're doing is very strange and will likely confuse anyone else that has to work with this code, this `setupSomething` function should be moved out of the other view if it doesn't actually do anything with the view's instance.

Comment: @muistooshort: There is nothing wrong with Sidd's answer. I applied the approach he mentioned in his answer and it seems to work now. I agree that the code might look confusing but it's an analogy of the actual code of a very big application. Not possible to write all of it. Anyways I had problem with passing object as param to `.call` and Sidd's method worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing objects and anything else (functions, arrays, what have you) is not the problem. My guess is that you are calling `setupSomething` from a context which doesn't have access to the `this` variable. The following methods would both work:

Using **call**:

```
function myView(){} 
myView.prototype.setupSomething = function(options){
  console.log(options.greeting + ' ' + this.name);
};
function guestView(name){
  this.name = name;
}
guestView.prototype.setupSomething = function(options){
  myView.prototype.setupSomething.call(this, options);
}
var guest = new guestView('Yogita');
guest.setupSomething({greeting:"hello"}); // "hello Yogita"
```

Using **bind**:

```
function myView(){}
myView.prototype.setupSomething = function(options){
  console.log(options.greeting + ' ' + this.name);
};
function guestView(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.setupSomething =  myView.prototype.setupSomething.bind(this); 
}
var guest = new guestView('Yogita');
guest.setupSomething({greeting : "namaste"}); // "namaste Yogita"
```

The second option allows you to create the same function on the `guestView` constructor and be able to call it directly with a `guestView`-created `this`. Note that it needs to be defined inside the constructor function in order to have access to the `this` value it is bound to.

**edit**

I just saw your added code. I am not familiar with Backbone or how you are calling the `render` function (the problem would actually reside there), so possibly the above is not much use, but I'll leave it here.